# проблема с открытием сайта после включения http2

Tags: nginx, https, браузер

```
~# nginx -V 
nginx version: nginx/1.9.9
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx
--with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module
--with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module
--with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module
--with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads
--with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail
--with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed'
--with-ipv6
```

Включаю поддержку http2 в директиве server на целевом сайте, и браузеры (chrome, firefox, opera) перестают его открывать, хотя в safari, qupzilla и в curl сайт открывается.
Выпадает со следующей ошибкой в хроме:

> ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

До этого была установлена версия nginx 1.9.4 со включенным spdy - все работало замечательно. 
Конфиг nginx не менялся после апдейта версии (ставилось из офф репозиториев nginx).

```
~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list 
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
```

Включенные директивы в блоке http:

```
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-bundle.crt;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!ADH:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
```

Включенные директивы в блоке server:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;
```

При этом выключаю http2 - во всех браузерах начинает все работать.

Проверка в https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest показывает:

> Next Protocol Negotiation (NPN)   Yes h2 http/1.1

В чем проблема?

Сайт находиться за программным NAT-шлюзом (iptables-rules), 
сертификат не самоподписанный - comodo PositiveSSL.

Answer (score 1):

Переместил директивы касающиеся настроек ssl из блока server { ... } в http {... } и все заработало ... 
[nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) 
Везде указаны оба контекста в качестве разрешенных